# Why does my custom validation function not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I am trying to implement custom validation functions in Sails models.

Without the custom function, all works fine.

With the function, it just conks out. Nothing is written to the DB, the callback is not called, the script just appears to end.

My code looks like this:

```
  module.exports = {
    attributes: {
      somefield: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        custom: function(value) {
          return true;
        }
      },
    }
  }
```

When I run it, it hits the custom function, returns true, but then just ends without an error and without calling the callback I am passing from the controller.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it's because I am working on version 0.12.14 but reading the documentation for 1.0.

Custom validation methods don't come into play until 1.0.

Bother.